# Macro for nodes in launch file

Tags: ros, pid, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use the [PID package](http://wiki.ros.org/pid) to control the joints of a snake robot. Since each node will be single controller, I need to start several nodes to control all the joints. The pid nodes have several parameters, so I hope to be able to write some form of macro that can make my launch file more compact and manageable. I found out that launch files are written in XML and not Xacro, so I can't use macros like you can for the URDF files.
Does anyone know a clever way to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252307/macro-for-nodes-in-launch-file/) by [Stian](https://answers.ros.org/users/28411/stian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-01-18

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2021-01-07**:\

> launch files are written in XML and not Xacro, so I can't use macros like you can for the URDF files

This is incorrect. `xacro` should be able to generate any xml format, and `xacro` is also in `xml` format.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2021-01-07**:
Specifically for `include`-ing a .launch file so this isn't exactly for `node`, but #q229489 is a good option that doesn't require customization (i.e. needed functionality is in the library).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know of a way to have macros or for loops in launch files.

One option is to have a separate [yaml](http://wiki.ros.org/rosparam#YAML_Format) file for each controller that contains the parameter values for a single controller. In your launch file you would have to list out each `<node>` separately but you could have something like this that uses the [rosparam](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/rosparam) tag:

```
<node pkg="pid" type="controller" name="pid1">
  <rosparam command="load" file="$(arg your_package)/config/pid1.yaml"/>
</node>
```

Repeat that block N times and have N yaml files. The `pid1.yaml` file would look like (follow the link above for more examples):

```
Kp: 1.0
Ki: 0.1
Kd: 0.2
upper_limit: 5.0
lower_limit: 0.2
windup_limit: 10.0
```

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2017-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1